# Change the transparency of v-menu on hover and selected

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I am looking to disable the opaqueness/transparency change that happens when the user hovers over a v-menu component. There is an initial change on hover, then a secondary change when the v-menu opens. I would like to only have the one change (the change on an open menu) but haven't been able to get the proper CSS working. Here is the v-menu example using on-hover that the documentation provides:

[Vuetify Play](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

I see that changing `v-hover-opacity: 0.4;` to `v-hover-opacity: 0.0;` in dev tools disables what I think I need disabled, but I am unsure the way to do it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve:

If you just want to change it for the one SFC, I would put a class on the `v-btn`, so that the change will not affect other btns in the component:

```html
<template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
  <v-btn
    class="transparent-overlay"
    ...
```

And then set scoped styles with a [`:deep`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors) selector to override styles for the overlay that holds the change in opacity:

```html
<style scoped>
  .v-btn.transparent-overlay:hover :deep(.v-btn__overlay){
    --v-hover-opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

---

If you want to change the overlay for all buttons, I would define a global rule in the main CSS:

```css
  .v-btn:hover > .v-btn__overlay{
    --v-hover-opacity: 0;
  }
```

---

If you want to target all buttons associated with `v-menu`, I think your best bet is to go by the `aria-haspopup` attribute:

```css
  .v-btn[aria-haspopup="menu"]:hover > .v-btn__overlay{
    --v-hover-opacity: 0;
  }
```

Note that this requires the props from the activator-slot to be put on the button (or adding the attribute manually). If you feel like this is too fragile, I would create a component around `v-menu` with the updated styles.